# React app - unable to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, reactjs, express

I want to connect my database to my react app however I'm very confused on how to do this. I made the database using SQL in SQL Server Management Studio. I've tried using express to connect it to my app however I know there's a lot missing from my code. What do I need to add/change to my code to connect it to my project?

UPDATE:

[image]

I made an express app and wrote some code in users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * from project_ideas', function (error, results, fields) {
   if (error) throw error;
   res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
 });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I added this code to App.js in the React app:

```
var React = require('react')
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      members: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(project_ideas => this.setState({ project_ideas: project_ideas }));
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="Ideas">
          <h1>Ideas</h1>
          {this.state.project_ideas.map(project_ideas =>
            <div key={project_ideas.id}>{project_ideas.idea}</div>
          )}
        </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a database client. For example [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

Then u can do something like this in users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    database: '...',
}

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/project_ideas', async (req, res, next) => {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config)

    let result = await pool.request().query('SELECT * from project_ideas');

    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the `config` enter the user, password and database name

If you want to use Windows Authentication you also need the package `msnodesqlv8` like described here in the [doc](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server).

So u have to do
`npm install msnodesqlv8`
and in ur code use this instead of the normal mssql import:

`const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');`

and change the config to:

```
const config = {
    server: 'localhost', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    database: 'Your Database Name',
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
}
```

Also you need to set a different route for your second `.get` otherwise it will always use the one which was declared first.

Comment: Thank you, this has really helped me gain more understanding on how to connect it however I don't have a password. I've updated my question with how I connect to the sql server. I just have a server name and authentication. @MatthiasV

Comment: Is the user `DESKTOP-6ON9\SK` in the Screenshot your Windows User or is it a domain user?

Comment: I believe it's a domain user. @MatthiasV

Comment: I have updated my answer so it also works with windows authentication. But keep in mind that this only works if the script runs with the same user u are using to authenticate on the sql server.